# Floating button over other views - Android

Tags: android, floating

I want to make a button or a view that is capable of showing up above `EditText`s
that when is clicked, certain action is performed upon that specific focused `EditText`. I don't know how it's called or if there is any 3d party library that does that.

Comment: Can you just post an image or something to elaborate what you actually want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's when [RelativeLayouts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) play a big role here since you could position views over another with the view on top having focus, and vice-versa. So first you'd compile Android's latest support design library into your local build.gradle file to use FAB, and then do something like this for the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    tools:context="com.davenotdavid.stackoverflow.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et1"
        android:hint="HINT..."
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et2"
        android:hint="HINT..."
        android:layout_below="@id/et1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et3"
        android:hint="HINT..."
        android:layout_below="@id/et2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

... and then perhaps test if the FAB has focus over a focused EditText by displaying a Toast message (as opposed to EditText's keyboard popping up) in your onCreate() as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    findViewById(R.id.fab).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "FAB clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```